# Title not updating after creation in premiere pro

Tags: premiere

I'm having this strange issue where I have created a title and when I try to update it (position or stroke) nothing happens. Either on or off the timeline, the title stays in its original position (off center) and it won't apply my changes.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

I'm running PP CC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple restart did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. Glad you figured it out.  Thanks for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Delayed reply but I just had the same issue. I found that toggling the roll/crawl options on and off triggered Premiere back into normal behaviour. This saves having to restart your project.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. I used one that was super practical but I don't remember it anymore. So now I reseting the workspace to default:

window -- workspace -- reset current workspace

This is not the best way, but if you don't have a great number of titles to edit, it might work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file "workingset" in C:\Users\Username\Documents\Adobe\Premiere Pro\6.0\Styles

It has helped me with different Title proplems, including this updating thing.